# initialization order of thread local variables

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, thread-local, thread-local-storage

A quote from N4713:

> Dynamic initialization of non-local variables V and W with static
>   storage duration are ordered as follows:
>   If V and W have ordered
>   initialization and V is defined before W within a single translation
>   unit, the initialization of V is sequenced before the initialization
>   of W.

Is there a similar paragraph for variables of thread storage duration? In the code below, is the initialization of `V` sequenced before the initialization
of `W`?

```
thread_local int V = 1;
thread_local int W = V;
```

**Updated:**

I want to modify the code as follows:

```
thread_local string V;
thread_local string W;
```

Answer (score 2):

From *6.7.2 Thread storage duration [basic.stc.thread]*:

> A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized before its first odr-use (6.2) and, if constructed,
>   shall be destroyed on thread exit.

This means that `V` is initialized before `W'.

Comment: What if there is no dependency and both need dynamic initialization?